# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parts'

Tags: python, package, python-import, importerror

I have the following files structure:

```
mytests
   models
      parts
        __init__.py
        ...
      __init__.py
      model.py
   test.py
```

This is the content of `__init__.py`:

```
from parts import *
from models import My_transformer

if __name__=='__main__':
    # ...
```

This is the content of `model.py`:

```
from parts.attention import Pre_Net

class My_transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,config,logger=None):
        super(My_transformer, self).__init__()
        ...
```

When I run `test.py`, I get the following error:

```
/mytests/models/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from parts import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parts'
```

at this line:

```
from models import My_transformer
```

How can I fix this error? I run the test.py from Jupyter Notebook.

**Update**

I have `__init__.py` inside `parts` and it looks as follows:

```
from attention import *

if __name__=='__main__':
    print('ok')
```

Comment: parts requires its own \_\_init\_\_.py. This is how python tells that parts is a package.

Comment: @MYousefi: Yes, I have `__init__.py` inside `parts`. Sorry for not mentioning it. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have structure and imports like these:

```
mytests
   models
      parts
        __init__.py
        attention.py
      __init__.py
      model.py
   test.py
```

`models/parts/__init__.py` content:

```
from .attention import Pre_Net
# or from .attention import *
```

`models/parts/attention.py` content:

```
class Pre_Net:
    pass
```

`models/__init__.py` content:

```
from .model import *
```

`models/model.py` content:

```
from models.parts import Pre_Net

class My_transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,config,logger=None):
        super(My_transformer, self).__init__()
        ...
```

`test.py` content:

```
from models import My_transformer
```

Comment: Thanks, just to say that `model.py` is located inside `models` rather than `models/parts`. Could you please update the answer accordingly to fit this structure?

Comment: @Fluxy I edited the answer. I don't really know what is inside your test.py, so I assumed that you want to import My_transformer in test.py module

Comment: That's ok. Thank you so much! Your answer helped fixing my issue!